# Match NSString in NSMutableArray to another NSMutableArray with string and save it in an array

Tags: objective-c, string-comparison

I am getting nearby places using google service. And know i have to filter those places containing these words..

```
_tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
    @"ability",
    @"academy",
    @"accolade",
    @"ace",
    @"active",
    @"body",
    @"burn",
    @"class",
    @"club",
    @"court",
    @"curve",
    @"dance",
    @"david",
    @"degree",
    @"fight",
    @"fit",
    @"gym",
    @"health",
    @"lab",
    @"leisure",
    @"muscle",
    @"perform",
    @"physique",
    @"promotion",
    @"recreation",
    @"sauna",
    @"shape",
    @"spa",
    @"strength",
    @"tone",
    @"training",
    @"west",
    @"workout",nil];
```

I searched it like ..

```
 NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textfield.text];

    substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
```

**searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring**

```
- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring//:(NSString *)substring
{
     [_matchplaces removeAllObjects];

//    int i=0;
//    for (NSString *word in dataToMatch)
//    {
//        if ([_tableData containsObject:word])
//        {
//           
//             [_matchplaces addObject: [_tableData objectAtIndex:i]];
//        }
//        
//        i++;
//    }

    int i=0;

    for(NSString *curString in _tableData)
    {
        NSComparisonResult result = [curString compare:[dataToMatch objectAtIndex:i] options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [[dataToMatch objectAtIndex:i] length])];

        //NSLog(@"result is %@",result);

        if (result == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            [_matchplaces addObject:curString];
        }
        i++;
    }

    [_tv reloadData];
}
```

This both ways i use in searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring only returns one value match.. can anybody suggest me why is it returning only one value match. or just share some code for matching.

Match words like this..

Or how could i use NSPredicate for matching string like

`Royal is MyGym is String`  contains `gym(Case insensitvie)`

Comment: May i ask the reason for down vote? I have shown my effort and code too. And ask a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string methods to check if a string contains another string:

```
if ([[dataToMatch objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:curString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
  // dataToMatch string contains the curString
}
```

iOS8 also has an `NSString` method `containsString` which is even simpler.